# Heroku rails app with a bootstrap theme styling is broken

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have an existing heroku rails 4 app that is styled correctly. It looks correct on my local machine/server. It is made with a bootstrap theme.

I just added a few extra css files (and some css lines to `application.css`) and now none of the css is working i.e. no custom styling.

My gemfile looks like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.1"
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production # for heroku
gem 'puma'
gem 'sucker_punch'
```

To tried to fix the problem by adding this to the `config/environments/production.rb` file

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

I also tried

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and then commited and pushed.

Nothing is working.

The css files are added to `app/assets/stylesheets`

And then in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` I have

```
/*
 *= require animate.min
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require_self
 */
body{padding:0;margin:0;font-family:'Open Sans','Trebuchet MS',arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px}
```

When I view the page's source and click on the css file it is filled with weird text. Here's a small bit of it:

```
book����mark����8���8���ìS���
```

Comment: have you tried to deploy it again?

Comment: Yes and it doesnt have any styling